# Bootstrap navbar seems to be longer than the actual content

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I am new to Bootstrap. The navbar looks like it is longer than my screen size. Its very right button is overlaped by the right side of the window. However, I cannot scroll the webpage to the right and see the whole navbar. It used to look fine but somehow it appeared to look like this:

[image]

```css
.navbar {
  padding-top: 6px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px gray;
  background-color: rgba(244, 139, 139, 0.8);
}
.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right a {
  margin-right: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Phenomena-Bold;
}
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #3b3c3d;
}
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav > li > a:active {
  color: #3b3c3d;
}
span.glyphicon-user {
  font-size: 20px;
}
span.glyphicon-shopping-cart {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: white
  /* change this to any color you want! */
  ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-light container-fluid navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills navbar-right">
        <li role="presentation"><a class="page-scroll" href="#">1</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="page-scroll" href="#">2</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="page-scroll" href="#">3</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="page-scroll" href="#">4</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="page-scroll" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a class="page-scroll" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
```

Comment: don't use row class.

Comment: @JasjeetSingh Oh, yes.. Thank you! :)

Comment: No problemo, happy to help

Comment: if you use row it must be inside a container. The reason behind row has -15 left and right margin. Containers have 15px inline padding on default. if you want to eliminate that padding this is where you should use rows.  Otherwise it will increase the width of your content.

Comment: @BerkKaya i didn't need neither a container nor a row. Just deleted both and all worked fine

Comment: @LeraZemlyanaya Working fine doesn't mean that you did it in a correct way.

Comment: @BerkKaya when i did this, the navbar started behaving strangely: it became much wider and its content moved out

Comment: @BerkKaya well.. Referring to the Bootstrap documentation, there should be a container but with no row: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills navbar-right">
                        <li role="presentation"><a class="page-scroll" href="#">1</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a class="page-scroll" href="#">2</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a class="page-scroll" href="#">3</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a class="page-scroll" href="#">4</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a class="page-scroll" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a></li>
                        <li role="presentation"><a class="page-scroll" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
```

Comment: Please use container class

Comment: Yes, there should be a container. Thank you!